# FragmentActivity and DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a DrawerLayout, it's works fine. This DrawerLayout open the Fragments and I did not create  FragmentActivity to control my Fragments.

In my App I have an Activity that do Login, if login is ok I'm start activity DrawerLayout. Now, I need control "back" of my Fragments, for example, in some fragments I need stop go back of device.

1 - The FragmentActivity really need to be created ?

2 - How can I stop back of fragment withou FragmentActivity ?

3 - If I need create FragmentActivity, how can I add the DrawerLayout ?

**XML DrawerLayout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dl"
     >

   <FrameLayout 
       android:id="@+id/fl"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"       
       >       
   </FrameLayout>

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/lv"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#e9ba68"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#ac453c"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
       >

   </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**DrawerLayout**

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    private ActionBar ab;
    private DrawerLayout dl;
    private ListView lv;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle tg;

    private List<ItensListView> fragments;
    private CharSequence tl; //titulo principal
    private CharSequence tlf; //titulo fragment 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_drawerlayout);  
        init();

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            selectedItem(0);
        }
    }

    private void init(){
        //actionbar
        onConfigActionBar();
        //listview
        configItensListView();
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);               
        lv.setAdapter(new DrawerLayoutListViewAdapter(this, fragments));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);        
        //drawerlayout
        dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dl);
        //actionbardrawertoggle
        tg = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.btmenu, R.string.nomeActionBar){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tl);                
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tlf);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };      
        dl.setDrawerListener(tg);

        tl = tlf = getTitle();      
    }

    /** ativa actionbar e botao home na action bar */
    private void onConfigActionBar(){
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        tg.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tg.syncState();
    }

    /** necessario */
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {           
        if (tg.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }            
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }


     /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_drawer_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean status = dl.isDrawerOpen(lv);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!status);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        selectedItem(position);     
    }

    /** open fragments */
    private void selectedItem(int position){
        FragmentTransaction ft;
        Fragment frag;
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                //frag = new InicioFrag();
                frag = new InicioFrag();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack("back");
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                frag = new ApresentacaoFrag();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack("back");
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                frag = new PerfilFrag();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack("back");
                ft.commit();
                break;

        }
```

**Login Activity**

```
public class LoginView extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private EditText etEmail;
    private EditText etSenha;
    private Button btCadastrar;
    private Button btEntrar;
    private Button btEsqueci;
    private Intent intentCadastrar;
    private Intent intentEsqueci;
    private Intent intentInicio;
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//remove barra de titulos
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

    private void doLogin(){
        if(etEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etSenha.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Informe todos os campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            progress = new CustomProgressDialog().getCustomProgress(null, LoginView.this);
            progress.show();

            Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.setEmail(etEmail.getText().toString());
            usuario.setSenha(etSenha.getText().toString());
            ApplicationController app = new UsuarioDAO().isUsuarioLogin(
                                                        usuario, 
                                                        new UsuarioAdapter(){
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void usuarioIsLogin(Boolean result) {
                                                                if(!result){
                                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ou senha inválido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                                                                }else{                                                                  
                                                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomDrawerLayout.class));
                                                                    finish();
                                                                }
                                                                progress.dismiss();
                                                        }

            });
            CustomVolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(app);          
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class ApresentacaoFrag extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apresentacao_view, container, false); 

        TextView txtView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvApresentacao);
        txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.apresentacao)));

        return  view;
    }

    private void alteraTextView(String texto){
        TextView txtView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tvApresentacao);
        txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.apresentacao)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The FragmentActivity really need to be created? How can I open fragment by clicking a button?

You're currently using `ActionBarActivity` which inherits `FragmentActivity`, so you already have `FragmentManager`. If you want to open fragment by clicking a button then add similar code in button's OnClickListener code: `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_to_which_attac‌​h_fragment, yourNewFragment).commit()`

> How can I stop 'back button pressed' event in fragment without FragmentActivity?

If I understand you correctly what you want is to 'override' the functionality of back button. Basically you need to understand that it is not Fragment who react to back button pressed event. It is always Activity who react and because Activity contains Fragment it can propagate back button pressed event to them. So implement `@Override public void onBackPressed() { \\do something here }` in Activity. Remember to do that in `ActionBarActivity`. `Fragment` doesn't have such a method. If you want to react in some way in your `Fragment` for back button pressed event then now from `onBackPressed()` method in your `ActionBarActivity` get a `Fragment` by `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` or `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag()` and call some of it's public methods.

> If I need create FragmentActivity, how can I add the DrawerLayout?

Simply set layout with DrawerLayout inside as your `ActionBarActivity` layout. Then inside that `DrawerLayout` keep `FrameLayout` to which you will add your fragments through `FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 0):

> The FragmentActivity really need to be created ?

Yes, it need to be created. You cannot create Fragments without FragmentActivity. FragmentActivity contains FragmentManager which manages Fragments. ActionBarActivity inherits from FragmentActivity.

> How can I stop back of fragment without FragmentActivity ?

You can not. Control your Fragments through FragmentManager.

> If I need create FragmentActivity, how can I add the DrawerLayout?

Simply set as your FragmentActivity layout layout with DrawerLayout inside. Then inside that DrawerLayout keep FrameLayout to which you will add your fragments through FragmentManager.

Comment: but ActionBarActivity inherits from FragmentActivity: `Extend Activity classes from ActionBarCompat: ActionBarCompat contains one Activity class which all of your Activity classes should extend: ActionBarActivity. This class itself extends from FragmentActivity so you can continue to use Fragments in your application. There is not a ActionBarCompat Fragment class that you need to extend, so you should continue using android.support.v4.Fragment as the base class for your Fragments.`

Comment: very nice. so, I have a FragmentActivity :) . But if I want open a Fragment from a button in my layout ?

Comment: If you want to open fragment by clicking a button then add similar code in button's `OnClickListener` code `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_to_which_attach_fragment, yourNewFragment).commit()`

Comment: wow, I do it, really works fine !!! But I have a screen that I want control "back" of device, you know ? If user press button "back" of device the screen doesn't back, can you understand ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly what you want is to 'override' the functionality of back button. You can do that by implementing `@Override public void onBackPressed() { \\do something here }` in Activity. If this is not what you want please explain further.. :)

Comment: exactly, but the method `onBackPressed()` I need override in `ActionBarActivity` or in my Fragment ?

Comment: In `ActionBarActivity`. `Fragment` doesn't have such a method.

Comment: very nice. I added a LogCat inside `onBackPressed()` and print. But how can I want disable back to fragment ? My fragment name is "MyFragmentTest"

Comment: If you want to react in some way in MyFragmentTest Fragment for back button pressed event then now from `onBackPressed()` method in your ActionBarActivity get a Fragment by `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` and call some of it's public methods.

Comment: Basically you need to understand that it is not Fragment who react to back button pressed event. It is always Activity who react and because Activity contains Fragment it can propagate back button pressed event to them. In a way which I described in previous comment.

Comment: very nice. now works. `@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  MyFragmentTest mf = (MyFragmentTest)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragmentTest");
  if(bsof.isVisible()){
   return;
  }else{
   super.onBackPressed();
  }
 }`

Comment: please, can you create an answer for me check with V solution ?

Comment: Ok, I try to summarize that :)

Comment: I created a new edited answer. See if it fit, and if yes accept.